# A piece of code working in WindowsFormApplication but not working in windows service, is there any mistake?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

Here the code is

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Thread thr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(run));
        thr.Start();
    }
    static void run()
    {


        while (true)
        {
            StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter("D:\\Sarojini.txt", true);
            str.WriteLine();
            str.WriteLine("**** List of Apllication*********");
            str.WriteLine();
            str.WriteLine("Service started on:" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
            str.WriteLine();
            str.WriteLine("the current user is  " + userName);
            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process process in processlist)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
                {
                    str.WriteLine("Process::{0}   ID::{1}   Title::{2}", process.ProcessName, process.Id, process.MainWindowTitle);

                }
            }
            str.Close();
            Thread.Sleep(3600000 / 10);
        }

    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter("D:\\Sarojini.txt", true);
        str.WriteLine();
        str.WriteLine("the service has been stopped.");


    }
```

here in this code , a text file is created and first line is written on it but the list of running application is not there , where as when i used this code in in windowsFormApllication it is running perfectly. i dont know what is the problem .

Comment: Add exception handling. The service probably crashes because of a permission issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the account you are running the service under not having the correct permissions to use the `Process` class. When trying to retrieve process names, IDs etc your application needs to have sufficient rights and the default **Local System Account** is unlikely to meet this.

When you run this code as a Windows Form Application `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` will return the user who is currently signed in.

When you run this code as a Windows Service `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` will return the user who setup under the User Account in the Service Setting.

This will show that they are running with different credentials. So, your service may be running under an account that does not have permission to perform the required actions.

To check this:

- Go into **Services** and double-click your service.
- Click on The **Log On** tab
- By default **Local System Account** is checked but you want to select **This Account** and set a valid account.

Comment: _"the correct permissions"_ - to do _what_? It is unclear what OP wants and what is causing the issue.

Comment: @CodeCaster - Thank you for your comment and I have tried to expand with some detail. You are right and without more information from OP we cannot pinpoint the exact line of failure this is a very common scenario where running as a form works and service doesn't and normally boils down to Local System Account vs User Account.

Comment: Thanks @Belogix   . As you said i checked it, and i have changed the account type but again i am getting an error like " Service Did not start Due to Log On failure ". So i want to know is it possible to do what i have tried above in my code.